# Mode of Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $X  \thicksim B(n,p)$
$$f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}n\\x\end{pmatrix}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}, x = 0,1,2, ..., n$$

Then solve the inequality $f(x) \ge f(x-1)$ and show that $f(x)$ become maximized when $x = [(n+1)p]$, which denotes the maximum integer equal to or smaller than $(n+1)p$.

---

I had solved given inequality and derived below inequality
$$x\le (n-x+1)p(1-p)$$ and if well summarized about x,

$$x\le \dfrac{p(1-p)(n+1)}{p(1-p)+1}$$

Anyhow could I derive above conclusion from this inequality?

Answer (score 0):

You made a msitake,

$$f(x)\geq f(x-1) \implies x\le \frac{(n-x+1)p}{(1-p)} \implies x \leq (n+1)p$$